# Avoid using child method in parent class in python

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

Suppose I have two classes in Python as below:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0

    def fun1(self):
        print 'p.fun1'

    def fun2(self):
        self.fun1()
        print 'p.fun2'
```

and

```
from parent import Parent

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child,self).__init__()

    def fun1(self):
        print 'c.fun1'

    def fun2(self):
        super(Child, self).fun2()
        print 'c.fun2'
```

and if I call `fun2` of Child

```
from child import Child

test = Child()
test.fun2()
```

I get output:

```
c.fun1
p.fun2
c.fun2
```

Which means the call of `Child.fun2()` leads to `Parent.fun2()`. But inside the `Parent.fun2()`, I use `self.fun1()` which in this case interpreted as `Child.fun1()` in my test.

But I really want the class `Parent` to be individual and the call of `Parent.fun2()` always uses `Parent.fun1()` inside it.

How can I avoid this?

I only know that I can make `Parent.fun1()` private into `Parent.__fun1()`. But I also have some instances of `Parent` where I need to use `Parent.fun1()` outside this class. That means I really need to override the `fun1()`.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. An instance of Parent will always call Parent.fun1, and an instance of Child will always call Child.fun1.

Comment: sorry for my unclearance. I want that: In the class `Parent` any uses of `self.fun1()` only refer to `Parent.fun1()`. In my test, since I create an instance of `Child`, the use of `Child.fun2()` lead to `Parent.fun2()`. And this call for `Parent.fun2()` calls for Child.fun1(), but I want it to call for `Parent.fun1()`. I hope the output become `p.fun1  p.fun2  c.fun2`

Comment: Then why do you implement `fun1` in the child class?

Comment: BTW, it's redundant to define a method in a derived class if all it does is call `super`, since that happens automatically if the method doesn't exist in the derived class. So you can get rid of the `__init__` in `Child`.

Comment: Thank you for your interests in my question. These codes are just a really simplified exemple of the problem I have encountered. For the fun1 in child class, I may need pass all data through a filter and do the same computation of fun1 in parent class. Surely, I won't override a method with just a super() ;)

Answer (score 2):

That's how inheritance is supposed to work. For the behavior you need, you might want to reconsider `Parent` & `Child` class's relationship, or change the method names or at least make the `Parent` methods `classmethods` or `staticmethods`.

This should work for your need, but I don't really like it.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num=0
    def fun1(self):
        print 'p.fun1'
    def fun2(self):
        Parent.fun1(self)
        print 'p.fun2'
```

`Child` class can remain the same.

In all classes accessed in the inheritance chain, `self` will always point to the instance of class actually instantiated and not the current class accessed in `super` call (or in order to find method/attribute for that matter). So `self.fun2` will always point to the method of `Child` class.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It's much more clear for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a mechanism called *Name Mangling*:

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.
>   Name mangling is helpful for letting subclasses override methods without breaking intraclass method calls
>   [Python Classes Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

This should work:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
    self.num = 0

    def fun1(self):
        print 'p.fun1'

    def fun2(self):
        self.__fun1()
        print 'p.fun2'

    __fun1 = fun1
```